# Android SearchView.getQuery() returns null

Tags: android, actionview, searchview

I have a search widget as a collapsible action view. I want to save the user entered query on device rotation. I have tried to use

searchView.getQuery().toString();

on different places in my code.

The problem I am facing is that it is always returning nothing/null. What can be the problem?

Comment: Does getQuery() return null or an empty string? If it returned null, your code would throw a null exception.